# ADT error exporting with Gradle

Tags: android, export, gradle, adt, android-studio

I'm trying to export my android project from ADT using Gradle so that I can import into Android Studio.

I select **Generate Gradle build files** and select my project in the Export menu, but when I click Finish it flashes the **Creating Gradle build** progress bar for a millisecond then stays on the Export menu screen. A new error is created in the Error Log: the message is blank, Plug-in is *com.android.ide.eclipse.adt*

This is the full error log output:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-05-20 16:16:45.168
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportPage.generateBuildfiles(GradleExportPage.java:293)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportWizard.performFinish(GradleExportWizard.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Export.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ExportResourcesAction.run(ExportResourcesAction.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /settings.gradle
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2169)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFile(Container.java:208)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.BuildFileCreator.createBuildFiles(BuildFileCreator.java:139)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportPage$6.run(GradleExportPage.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    ... 53 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /settings.gradle
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.newResource(Workspace.java:2169)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Container.getFile(Container.java:208)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.BuildFileCreator.createBuildFiles(BuildFileCreator.java:139)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportPage$6.run(GradleExportPage.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportPage.generateBuildfiles(GradleExportPage.java:293)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.exportgradle.GradleExportWizard.performFinish(GradleExportWizard.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$Export.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.run(CommandAction.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.ExportResourcesAction.run(ExportResourcesAction.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BaseSelectionListenerAction.runWithEvent(BaseSelectionListenerAction.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I tried looking up the Java errors and `Path must include project and resource name: /settings.gradle` as it pertains to ADT but I wasn't able to find anything. I'm not familiar with Gradle so I'm not sure what's causing this. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem on a Mac, how did you get this error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the error is, but this part of the code is being completely rewritten to better handle various (multi) project setups. Hopefully we'll have an update out soon to fix this.

Comment: if you have no dependencies at all, it should have, I think.